# SQL Query for selecting multiple rows but highest value for each PK

Tags: mysql, sql

I know that the title sounds horrible but I have no idea how to summarize it better. I'm pretty sure that somebody had the same problem before but I couldn't find anything. RDBMS: MySQL.

**Problem:**
I have the following (simplified) table:

```
+------+------------+---------------------------------+
| name | date       | score                           |
+------+------------+---------------------------------+
| A    | 01.01.2015 | 1                               |
| A    | 01.02.2015 | 3                               |
| A    | 01.03.2015 | 4                               |
| B    | 01.01.2015 | 3                               |
| B    | 01.02.2015 | 4                               |
| B    | 01.03.2015 | 5                               |
| C    | 01.01.2015 | 1                               |
| C    | 01.02.2015 | 2                               |
| C    | 01.03.2015 | 3                               |
+------+------------+---------------------------------+
```

There is no unique constraint or PK defined.

The table represents a highscore of a game. Every day the score of all players are inserted with values that are: name, points, now(),...

The data represent a snapshot of the score of each player at a specific time.

I want the most recent entry for each user only but only for the highest X players. So the result should look like

```
+------+------------+---------------------------------+
| name | date       | score                           |
+------+------------+---------------------------------+
| A    | 01.03.2015 | 4                               |
| B    | 01.03.2015 | 5                               |
+------+------------+---------------------------------+
```

- C doesn't appear since he's not in the top 2 (by score)
- A appears with the most recent row (by date)
- B appears, like A, with the most recent row (by date) and because he is in the top 2

I hope it becomes clear what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google and learn about "GROUP BY" and MAX() in SQL.

Comment: So, is the logic to grab a list of the `max(date)` for each Name and also grab a list of `max(Score), name... ORDER BY maxscore desc LIMIT 2` and then only return results where the two lists match?

Comment: Let's say there are names A, B, C, D, E and F. For each of them multiple rows exist with different dates and scores. The more recent the date the higher the score (if a player is active of course). So what I want is the most recent rows (by date) for each of A, B, C, D, E and F. Optionally it'd be great to limit that as well to the 5 (or whatever) players with the highest score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that what you need is to first select the X players who've gotten the highest score and then get their latest performance. In this case, you should do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename t
JOIN
(
  SELECT t.name, max(t.date) as max_date
  FROM tablename t
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT name 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT name, max(score) as max_score
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY name
    ) all_highscores
    ORDER BY max_score DESC
    LIMIT X
  ) top_scores
  ON top_scores.name = t.name
  GROUP BY t.name
) top_last
on t.name = top_last.name
and t.date = top_last.date;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!! I can adapt that to my needs, I appreciate your help!